Ubuntu Server in Emergency Mode
Hello Ubuntu community,
I encountered an issue after resizing my root filesystem and I’m hoping someone can help me resolve it.
Problem:
I resized my root filesystem using the resize2fs command. After receiving a success message from the resize operation, I rebooted the device. However, the server immediately went into emergency mode, and the root filesystem is now mounted in read-only mode. I’m unable to make changes to system files like /etc/fstab or troubleshoot effectively due to the read-only state.
What I did:

I used the following command to resize the root partition:

 sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root

After successful completion, I rebooted the device:
sudo reboot


Current Situation:

The server enters emergency mode on every boot.
The root filesystem is mounted as read-only, so I can't edit critical system files like /etc/fstab.
I'm unable to mount it with write permissions normally.

Steps I've Tried:

Rebooted the system into GRUB recovery mode, but I need more specific instructions on how to proceed with fixing the issue.

Attempted to remount the root filesystem with:
mount -o remount,rw /
But this only works temporarily during recovery mode and doesn’t persist across reboots.


Question:
How can I safely revert or troubleshoot this resizing operation? Are there steps to recover from this emergency mode and return to normal boot?
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

After messing with partitions and having this issue the fastest and only 100 percent fix is a reinstall of the OS.

I want to back up the data as well how can i do it ?

You can not you mess up the hard drive all is lost. Sorry.

All is not necessarily lost. This question is similar to: What does this message mean and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot? "... You are in emergency mode. ...". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Once remount using,
mount -o remount,rw /

Verify that the filesystem is remounted as read-write using the mount command or by attempting to create a file (e.g., touch /testfile)
Check Filesystem Integrity, using
fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root

If it finds any issues, it will ask whether to fix them. Answer with y to proceed.
now, Check and Edit /etc/fstab
The root filesystem may be incorrectly referenced in /etc/fstab, causing the system to fail to mount it properly. Open the /etc/fstab file and review it for any incorrect entries:
nano /etc/fstab

Confirm the UUID of your root partition matches the one in /etc/fstab using the following command to get the UUID:
blkid
UUID=<your-root-partition-uuid> / ext4 defaults 0 1

Ensure that your disk isn't out of space or inodes, as this could cause the read-only state as well:
df -h
df -i

now you can reboot the server..
If the Server Still Boots into Emergency Mode:
journalctl -xb

dmesg | grep -i fs


If errors or warnings appear in the logs, they can give you further clues about what went wrong during the resizing process or with the mount.
// Rebuild the Initramfs (Optional)
Sometimes after resizing the root partition, you may need to rebuild the initramfs to ensure the system boots correctly. You can do this by running:
update-initramfs -u

and reboot..
